# from where SSL ConnectionResetError comes from?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

## TL;DR

My question is simple - where is the code responsible to **raise** `ConnectionResetError` on cpython3 following a call to `self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)` on `ssl.py`?

## Background

I'm getting sometimes [`ConnectionResetError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ConnectionResetError) when trying to connect to S3 with ssl. this error occurs rarely so its tricky to reproduce it.

```
# trimmed stacktrace
File "/MYPROJECT/MY_FUNC.py", line 123, in <genexpr>
rows = (row for row in reader)
File "/XXX/lib/python3.6/csv.py", line 112, in _next_
row = next(self.reader)
File "/XXX/lib/python3.6/tarfile.py", line 706, in readinto
buf = self.read(len(b))
File "/XXX/lib/python3.6/tarfile.py", line 695, in read
b = self.fileobj.read(length)
File "/XXX/lib/python3.6/gzip.py", line 276, in read
return self._buffer.read(size)
File "/XXX/lib/python3.6/_compression.py", line 68, in readinto
data = self.read(len(byte_view))
File "/XXX/lib/python3.6/gzip.py", line 469, in read
buf = self._fp.read(io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
File "/XXX/lib/python3.6/gzip.py", line 91, in read
self.file.read(size-self._length+read)
File "/XXX/lib/python3.6/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 1311, in read
self._fetch(self.loc, self.loc + length)
File "/XXX/lib/python3.6/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 1292, in _fetch
req_kw=self.s3.req_kw)
File "/XXX/lib/python3.6/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 1496, in _fetch_range
return resp['Body'].read()
File "/XXX/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/response.py", line 74, in read
chunk = self._raw_stream.read(amt)
File "/XXX/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 239, in read
data = self._fp.read()
File "/XXX/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 462, in read
s = self._safe_read(self.length)
File "/XXX/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 612, in _safe_read
chunk = self.fp.read(min(amt, MAXAMOUNT))
File "/XXX/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 586, in readinto
return self._sock.recv_into(b)
File "/XXX/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1009, in recv_into
return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
File "/XXX/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 871, in read
return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
File "/XXX/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 631, in read
v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

## What i've tried

looking at `ssl.py:631` gives me no further clues - **we have to go deeper!:**

```
    def read(self, len=1024, buffer=None):
    """Read up to 'len' bytes from the SSL object and return them.

    If 'buffer' is provided, read into this buffer and return the number of
    bytes read.
    """
    if buffer is not None:
        v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)  # <--- exception here
    else:
        v = self._sslobj.read(len)
    return v
```

i've tried searching it [on CPython repo](https://github.com/python/cpython/search?l=Python&p=1&q=ConnectionResetError) but AFAICS nothing seems to raise it, i suspect its hidden in SSL implementation or on some mapping between `OSError` to `ConnectionError` subclasses.

my final goal is to write py2 & py3 compatible code for handling this exceptions (`ConnectionError` is new on py3) by comparing the module's py2 & py3 versions that raises this error.

## Update - py2 & py3 catch for `ConnectionError` subclasses

my question origins was to find a way to catch `ConnectionError` and its subclasses on python2 & python3, so here it is:

```
import errno

# ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ConnectionError
_CONNECTION_ERRORS = frozenset({
    errno.ECONNRESET,  # ConnectionResetError
    errno.EPIPE, errno.ESHUTDOWN,  # BrokenPipeError
    errno.ECONNABORTED,  # ConnectionAbortedError
    errno.ECONNREFUSED,  # ConnectionRefusedError
})

try:
    ...
except OSError as e:
    if e.errno not in _CONNECTION_ERRORS:
        raise
    print('got ConnectionError - %e' % e)
```

Comment: so, what is your question then, would you edit it to clarify a bit?

Comment: the question is same as written in TL;DR and your answer seems to be correct :) but i want to wait a bit longer before accepting to see if any other answers appear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ConnectionResetError` is raised when [`errno`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/errno) is `ECONNRESET`. `errno` is how libc indicates whether or not an error occurred in a system call.

You could search `ConnectionResetError` in `Objects/exceptions.c` to find out how this exception type get initialized and added to `errnomap` dict.

In the case of `self._sslobj.read` raised `ConnectionResetError`, `_sslobj.read` is implemented with `_ssl__SSLSocket_read_impl`, the actual ssl read is done with openssl's `SSL_read`:

```
count = SSL_read(self->ssl, mem, len);
_PySSL_UPDATE_ERRNO_IF(count <= 0, self, count);
```

as the error occurred, `_PySSL_UPDATE_ERRNO_IF` will set `(sock)->ssl_errno = SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL` and `(sock)->c_errno = ECONNRESET`.

later, in `PySSL_SetError`:

```
    err = obj->ssl_errno;
    switch (err) {
    ...
    case SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL:

        if (obj->c_errno) {
            errno = obj->c_errno;
            return PyErr_SetFromErrno(PyExc_OSError);
        }
```

`PyErr_SetFromErrno(PyExc_OSError)` equals with:

```
OSError(errno.ECONNRESET, 'Connection reset by peer', ...)
```

when `OSError` constructs with an `errno`, [it will lookup a more specified subclass](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.5/Objects/exceptions.c#L970-L974), by lookup `errno` value in the aforementioned `errnomap` dict:

```
newtype = PyDict_GetItem(errnomap, myerrno);
if (newtype) {
    assert(PyType_Check(newtype));
    type = (PyTypeObject *) newtype;
}
```

it actually returns and raises out a `ConnectionResetError` exception.